# Need to convert xml parsing to json parsing

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-7, json.net

Hi i have a twiiter app which calls api v1, which is a xml output.

With twiter api v1.1 the output is in json format.

The xml parsing code is

```
 var xmlElement = XElement.Parse(response.Content);
        var statusList = (from item in xmlElement.Elements("status")
                          select new ItemViewModel
                          {
                              UserName = GetChildElementValue(item, "user", "screen_name"),
                              DisplayUserName = GetChildElementValue(item, "user", "name"),
                              TweetText = (string)item.Element("text"),
                              CreatedDate = GetCreatedDate((string)item.Element("created_at")),
                              Image = GetChildElementValue(item, "user", "profile_image_url"),
                              Id = (long)item.Element("id"),
                              NewTweet = true,
                              Source = (string)item.Element("source"),
                          }).ToList();
```

Now i need to change this code to parse json output.

Anybody help please.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest change would be to port your LINQ to XML code to use LINQ to JSON from [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx)

Documentation: [Querying JSON with LINQ](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/?topic=html/QueryingLINQtoJSON.htm)